# Loop through Filenames with spaces Bash using variables

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am using the following script to iterate over a folder structure, however folders contains space in between is skipped.

```
for i in $(echo $File_Directory | sed "s/\// /g")
do
    if [ -d $i ]
    then
        echo "$i directory exists."
    else
        echo "Creating directory $i"
        `mkdir $i`
    fi
done
```

Appreciate help on this..

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Why are you replacing path separator characters (`/`) with spaces? Why are you calling `mkdir`? What are the contents of `$File_Directory`, and what exactly do you want each iteration of the loop to do?

Comment: If your intention is to create the missing directories, you could use `mkdir -p "$path"` instead - it will create the missing directories.

Comment: Furthermore, `\`mkdir $i\`` will take the output of `mkdir $i` and try to run it as a command.

Comment: This script is not like `mkdir -p` because it is attempting to create all the component directories in the current directory -- no hierarchy

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, but is that intentional, or just another bug in the code shown?

Comment: We await word from @sam

Comment: $File_Directory = A/B/C/d. My requirement is to create the same folder structure. first create folder A, then subfolder B, then subfolder C, so on. However if there is a space in any of the folder name, this login doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the whole loop ought to be `mkdir -p "$File_Directory"` ...
But assuming he *meant* to put them all in the same dir:

```
$: File_Directory=a/b/c/d/e/f/g
$: ( IFS=/; for d in $File_Directory; do mkdir -p "$d"; done; )
```

That does play a little fast and loose with the parameter parsing though.